# Best way to test complex user flows in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am creating an end to end testing solution in Cypress for an application which essentially has the following flow:

Admin Creates user -> User validates their account -> User logs in -> User is able to perform various actions and go through a long process flow

I have previously created long custom commands in cypress to handle this (eg cy.login, cy.createUser()) but this doesn't look great and I feel this will become harder to manage as I add more tests.

So my question is, is there a recommended pattern that I should be using to generate user flows for testing in Cypress?

I would like to introduce dynamic data into the flow the user goes onto (which involves a lot of form filling). But not sure the best way to go about this.

Comment: may be this help to proceed further or to get an idea. https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/recipes.html#Testing-the-DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, I believe if you follow concepts like page object model, data-driven testing you will be able to find the best solution that suits you.
I would tell you the way I would design it, but this is not the only way to do it. I'm suggesting you this way since there are many user flows, and there are inter depending user flows. If we take those flows,

- Admin Creates user
- User validates their account
- User logs in
- User is able to perform various actions ..etc

These can be categorized as different test scenarios (You can take a page as a test scenario). The reason to do it is, this will make it easier for you to manage page specific tests.

Then you can store the identifiers of each page separately so you can call them when needed. (Read more about page object model)

Then I prefer to manage separate JSON files to store test scenarios
Eg UserLoginData.jsom

```
{
"Valid Login":{"UN":"UserName", "Pass":"Password","Error":false},
"InValid Login":{"UN":"UserName", "Pass":"Password","Error":false},
}
```

Later you can loop through the keys and treat them as test cases. In the integration - test file, you can automatically generate the test cases using the keys. So, when your data grows, your tests will grow.

Then, without using custom functions, you can use a selected valid dataset when you want to generate a pre-requisite for the tests. For example, for user login, a valid registration will be a pre-requisite.

I have mentioned a basic Idea of a bigger plan, you can add and remove points from this and customize your test as you like.

Ps: Please bear with me if I have made any spelling mistakes, as I'm using one hand for coding due to a dislocated right.
Cheers!